# What is DX technology and what are the effects on digital cameras?

Tags: electromagnetism, photons, power, electrical-engineering, solar-cells

I am photographing in a high power voltage field in Industry producing aluminium, called [DX technology](http://www.dubal.ae/our-technologies/growth-through-technology/dx-technology.aspx).

How do I know if my digital camera will not be affected? At 350kA current my film cameras were just fine. At 380kA current the film negatives came up blurry. How do I know if my Digital SLR Canon and lenses will work? Are there physical side effects to the body? Are there any other risks to consider?

Answers with minimal technical terms are preferred.

Comment: Note that *DX Technology* is a brand name for [an electrolysis cell made by DUBAL](https://www.dubal.ae/our-technologies/growth-through-technology/dx-technology.aspx).

Comment: Hi Yes I know. I just cant figure out how it works.

Comment: Hi Katarina. My comment was meant for other site members who may never have seen an aluminium smelter. I can't think of any reason why the cell should have affected a film camera. I'd guess it generates a magnetic field field, but I'm surprised that the field is strong enough to affect a camera.

Comment: The magnetic fields in aluminum smelters are quite strong. At 5m distance a current of 350,000A will produce a field of 140Gauss or 0.014T. In a smelter you may be closer than that and there is usually not one such current but dozens. If you take two ferrous coins or washers, they will stick together quite strongly (the smelter folks like to demonstrate that effect). The magnetic parts in your cameras will, of course, do the same. I would suggest to make a simple magnetic shield from sheet metal. The stuff used to make rain gutters is cheap and easy to use and should suffice.

Comment: Or use a long lens :-) to the limit of your ability to shoot from farther away.